# Getting a tidy print from top

Tags: command-line, sed, pipe, top

```
 PID                                   %CPU %MEM            COMMAND                                                           
 719011 ----      --   0  ----  --- ---- -  0.7  1.3 606:58.25 dvaudio_server                                                                                   
 719012 ----      --   0  ----  --- ---- -  0.7  1.3 606:58.25 dvaudio_server                                                                                   
 719013 ----      --   0  ----  --- ---- -  0.7  1.3 606:58.25 dvaudio_server                                                                                   
 719014 ----      --   0  ----  --- ---- -  0.7  1.3 606:58.25 dvaudio_server                                                                                   
 719015 ----      --   0  ----  --- ---- -  0.7  1.3 606:58.25 dvaudio_server                                                                                   
 719016 ----      --   0  ----  --- ---- -  0.7  1.3 606:58.25 dvaudio_server
```

Is it possible to achieve the above result from top just by issuing an accumulation of commands piped together then saving to a file?

I have tried various ways but all give messy results.

Is there anyway of getting this information only using the pPID? This will then save having to write every child-PID in the command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR

```
top -b -n1 | sed '1,6d'
```

## **Long answer**

You could use the `-b` option of `top` :

> ```
>   -b : Batch mode operation
>         Starts top in 'Batch mode', which could be useful for 
>         sending output from  top  to other programs  or  to  
>         a file.  In this mode, top will not accept input and runs
>         until the iterations limit you've set with the '-n' 
>         command-line option  or  until killed.
> ```

This basically makes `top` non-interactive.
You can then pipe any command as you wish, and redirect the output to a file of your choice.

As said in the man, you may want to use the `-n` option in order to not to have to kill the process. If you want the process to stop as soon as it shows the result, use the `-n 1` value.

`sed -'1,6d'` will get rid of the ressources usage summary (the first 6 lines of the output).

### Edit

Possible duplicate of [get `top` output for non interactive shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255100/get-top-output-for-non-interactive-shell).

Comment: Thank you, thank you thank you! this has been driving me nuts! The worst bit......all I was missing was the 1!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome! That's always the little bit that matters :P